# Should there be a Prism . UnloadModule? (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: module, xamarin.forms, prism-6

I'm interested in having many dynamic assemblies loaded on demand.

Since it's possible all these modules may create too much memory pressure, I want to unload them when directed by the OS, or when lack of activity is detected.

How can I unload a previously loaded module?  Is quitting the app the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unload a previously loaded module.

briannoyes stated:

> This is a limitation of .NET, once an assembly is loaded there is no way to unload it unless you restart the process or load it in a separate appdomain, which opens up a whole separate can of worms we decided not to pursue back in Prism 1.

[Source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/3)

You may try to let unused objects garbage collected and don't hold them in static containers.